# sveltekit how to bust caches css and javascript

Tags: sveltekit

how to bust cache css and js?

I tried putting the meta tags in the layout page. it doesn't seem to work at all

```js
<svelte:head>
    <meta name="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta name="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta name="Expires" content="0" />
</svelte:head>
```

when I update javascript in the code, then I push it to vercel hosting. Open the browser and enter the website. then press refresh. Nothing happen. still got the same old javascript. I gotta press cmd+shift+R to do a hard refresh to make sure. then the new js code is reflected.

Now how prevent the browser from caching js and css ?

Comment: Why would you need this? Assets should be hashed anyway.

Comment: it hashed, but when will the hash change ?

Comment: I update the js and check the file name,  the hash doesn't change

Comment: Did you run a build? The files are only updated on build, not in dev mode.